# Macbook air M1 - Repeated kernel panics because of display/external hub

Tags: display, hardware, kernel-panic

I've used my Macbook air M1 for about three month and already got about 15+ crashes/reboots. Whenever this happened, I hadn't been doing anything special, nothing that was related to any installed software.

I have noticed that other people are describing similar problems online, but I am not an expert, and I am very scared that these crashes might damage my computer in a permanent way.

All in all my questions are:

> **Q1.** Is my computer at risk of *death*? I can stand these reboots, even if they irritate me, but I cant afford it to suddenly be permanently fried.

> **Q2.** Is the problem software or hardware?

> **Q3.** More specifically, what is the problem?

> **Q4.** Is there something I can do?

I am quite sure that the problem is related, even caused, by the interaction between my computer and my monitor (or the external hub to which it is attached). I have tried different monitors and the problem keeps coming (even though less frequently with a more recent monitor).

---

**Update**: Since I installed the beta of Monterey the problem has completely been solved.

---

I am appending the report below.

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xfffffe0030ab5798): "dart-disp0 (0xfffffe2332fdc000): SMMU(SMMU) error: SID 0 PTE invalid exception on read with DVA 0x2454000 (TTBR 0 SEG 0x1 PTE 0x115) ERROR_STATUS 0x80000004 TIME 0x72d5fd345b2f TTE 0 AXI_ID 0)"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20F71
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: FB10CC0AB8BAC020BC47A50D64476F11
Kernel UUID: 07259C53-9EF7-32FF-821D-8F28A5985DFA
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.120.36
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x00000000278dc000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe002e8e0000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000028424000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe002f428000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002f4f4000
mach_absolute_time: 0x2c18d463d28
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x60ae8298 0x0009dab1
  Sleep   : 0x60b09b50 0x000d7f9f
  Wake    : 0x60b09c46 0x0006a6a4
  Calendar: 0x60b14843 0x0007d704

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f4
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f4
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f4
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f8
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f665240
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f8
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe002f6666f8
Panicked task 0xfffffe1666e85a20: 46551 pages, 36 threads: pid 19141: com.apple.WebKit
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe1679c25320, backtrace: 0xfffffe304dc7f4f0, tid: 999786
          lr: 0xfffffe002f542be4  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7f560
          lr: 0xfffffe002f5429c8  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7f5d0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f66ba70  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7f5f0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f65d2b8  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7f6a0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f4fb7e8  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7f6b0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f542658  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fa40
          lr: 0xfffffe002f542658  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fab0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fcf43e8  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fad0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030ab5798  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fd40
          lr: 0xfffffe0030ab5270  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fdd0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030ab4a5c  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fe80
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc21ec0  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fec0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc57dc0  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7ff20
          lr: 0xfffffe00306628c8  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7ffb0
          lr: 0xfffffe002fc489e0  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7ffc0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f65fce0  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7ffe0
          lr: 0xfffffe002f4fb85c  fp: 0xfffffe304dc7fff0
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART(1.0)[F6E1E036-504F-3FDF-B83B-6732226FF906]@0xfffffe0030ab0000->0xfffffe0030ab7fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe002fe50000->0xfffffe002fe9ffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily(1)[55309CB3-D624-3B9B-962A-E82571B663FC]@0xfffffe0031588000->0xfffffe003159bfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController(1.0d1)[E7931F7A-8581-32B7-8A33-394B279B926C]@0xfffffe0030660000->0xfffffe0030663fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[F784412E-33CC-3859-B0CB-D0A62C9E26CB]@0xfffffe002fe50000->0xfffffe002fe9ffff

last started kext at 511273126578: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm 5.0.0 (addr 0xfffffe002ef04000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostBillboardDevice    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  436.121.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4050.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.120.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.28.1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   381
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.3
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  405.39
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.6.1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4050.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   224
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   985.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.28.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.28.1
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    3.55.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   16.15.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    985.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.5d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.5d7
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.1
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.120.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.121.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.121.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.8.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 385640 (Uncompressed 977696) **
```

Comment: Have you tried a different hub

Comment: @mmmmmm, thanks for the question.   Yes! The previous hub was even worse, now I use a anker 8-to-1, which is supposed to be a high quality hub.

Comment: Do you have the hub connected to a power supply when you get the panics?

Comment: @Gilby I saw online people claiming that the problem is the connection of the hub with the power supply, so I am not connecting it to it, still the problem appears.

Comment: Not specific to your hub, but in general powered hubs are more reliable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this particular type of kernel panic does not in itself represent any form of risk of death of your computer in terms of actually damaging the hardware.

The problem is almost certainly a software bug. It could be a hardware error as welll, but it is unlikely.

It is impossible to give you the exact "problem description" from just the information given in your question. However, you can get quite a few details from the panic report itself:

In rough terms, the panic reports details that the memory management unit responsible for I/O raised an unexpected error while attempting a read from memory (RAM).

Here's an explanation for some of the terms found in the first line of the panic report:

dart-disp0: "Device Address Resolution Table" for display controller 0

SMMU: "System Memory Management Unit"

SID: "stream id"

PTE: "Page table entry"

DVA: "Device virtual address"

The DART is really an memory management unit specifically for I/O (i.e. peripherals) - and it has to cooperate with the main system memory management unit in order to, well, manage memory. The purpose of an I/O memory management unit is to facilitate access to main memory for peripherals - for example when doing DMA transfers - which is basically devices accessing main memory directly without participation of the CPU. Essentially this makes it possible to have devices access main memory in a performant way, while stay obeying restrictions and mappings set up by the operating system (such as for example address translation, read-only zones, etc).

On ARM systems, the stream ID is basically a number that makes it possible for the IOMMU (DART) to make lookups in the stream table to find the mappings and configuration relevant for a specific peripheral device.

The page table entry is a generic terms for a configuration of a memory management unit that maps adresses from virtual address space into physical address space.

The device virtual address is simply a memory address given by the peripheral, before it is eventually translated into a physical memory address by the IOMMU.

In simpler terms this means that somehow a read from memory initiated by a peripheral device related to the display controller triggered an unexpected error. That could be a bug in the operating system, or more likely it would be a driver bug where some page table configuration made with the IOMMU is incorrect. It could also be a problem with a hub or display that does "something" out of spec that wasn't anticipated by Apple - although I would classify it is a macOS bug that the system crashes like this.

In terms of what you can do yourself - I would advise trying to use the computer without the hub for a while. Does this stop the kernel panics? - If so, contact the vendor for support and/or replace the hub with something else. I would also report the bug to Apple as you do not seem to have third party drivers (kernel extensions) loaded in. Also as soon as a software update is available for macOS, I would load that in to see if a fix was included.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete question. I do not use the hub/monitor the whole day, I use it only until dinner, then I use the macbook as a laptop, and I can confirm that the issue happens only when the mac is attached to the hub/monitor.

Answer (score -1):

its a hub/monitor issue. same issue myself. i used my MacBook without the hub/monitor adapter for 3 months straight and never an issue. that is how I I know for sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).